# Group policy does not work on Windows 10 home edition?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, windows-update, group-policy, windows-defender

I'm using Windows 10 home edition, try to solve update Windows Defender Antivirus antimalware platform - KB4052623 (Version 4.18.2001.10) error code 0x80070643

According to this Microsoft web [page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052623/update-for-windows-defender-antimalware-platform), I might need to edit the Group Policy.
Btw, I tried all other fixes include fresh install window itself, none worked, this is the last method I haven't tried.

So, I installed the gpedit.msc on my home edition, based on this web [page](https://www.itechtics.com/easily-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-10-home-edition/).

gpedit.msc runs fine, but it seems gpedit won't change any values or keys in windows registry.
I'm using this [site](https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/) for reference:

For [example](https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#10998), gpedit made no change to registry key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender`.

Did I miss anything or did I completely miss understood how group policy works?
I thought gpedit just change the registry.

Comment: I reviewed a number of articles on adding GPedit to Home. Most all of them are 2 years old or older, and subject to the vagaries of every changing Windows 10 - new Version out next week. Best to upgrade to Pro to get this feature.

Comment: @John Thanks for the answer, but I'm just looking for a fix for update error, if not for the update problem I won't even touch group policy, so I probably won't upgrade to pro edition. But like you said new version out soon, so hopefully they will fix this update error

Comment: It is hard to say at this point whether V2004 will fix the Defender issue

Comment: Have you tried running `sfc /scannow` to check for corrupt system files? If that command did not find any issues, try cleaning out `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution` and checking for updates.

Comment: @michaelg Yes, I did that long time ago, I been having this problem since Sept. last year, back then the platform version is 4.18.1908.7(I keep a journal for this kinda thing), I can fix the problem by either system restore or [in-place upgrade](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/videoplayer/embed/RE201WL). And I been keep having this problem like every platform update since then(Oct. 2nd, 4.18.1909.6; Oct. 28th, 4.18.1910.4; Dec. 7th, 4.18.1911.3; Feb. 4th 2020, 4.18.2001.7). Like I said I tried everything including the one you mentioned other than gpedit, none of them worked for 4.18.2001.10.